# How to make blur textview when the data is loading

Tags: android, textview, transition, loading, blur

I have a textview, when I load the data and set the data to my textview, I want to make a blur textview, when the data isn't load.
I want like this
[image: TextView blur when data is loading]
[image: TextView blur when data is loading]

and then if data loaded it is like this
[image: Textview normal when data is loaded]

I have tried it, but I still can't make blur in textview when loading. anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this using color animations. I basically have 2 recyclerviews, one for the blur, and one for the actual data that needs to be displayed. When the data is loaded, I swap the recyclerviews.
You can check it out on my project here https://github.com/PabiMoloi/CutCrease/tree/develop?files=1